# Getting html source from site after logging in with cURL

Tags: php, http, curl

I've used cURL with PHP to log into a site in order to get data from it. Logging in works fine, however I wish to use this session to navigate other parts of the site where login is required. I can't seem to do this.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The response cURL receives is the source of the pages.